# Only homepage loads following migration (WordPress, nginx)

Tags: wordpress, migration

following a migration from a shared platform to a private cloud server only the home page is loading.

After looking around the most common fix appears to be flushing the perma links and modifying the .htaccess with the following:

AllowOverride All

However the server uses nginx, after trying a .htaccess to nginx converter with the following code added to nginx.conf:

```
location / {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
  }
}
```

However I had no luck with this.

Any assistance is appreciated - I hope this is sufficient information but let me know if not.

Thank you.

Comment: Nevermind I should have spent more time looking - eventually found https://nginxlibrary.com/wordpress-permalinks/

Answer (score 0):

Rename .htaccess to some other name, lets say .htaccess1, then go to Settings -> Permalinks, Select Post Name and hit save. It will generate new .htaccess and see if it fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read and comment. Unfortunately I cannot use a .htaccess as the server runs nginx however I should have spent more time looking as I eventually found https://nginxlibrary.com/wordpress-permalinks/